# Pull url from string

Tags: python, django

I have the string below I'm trying to pull the url out of out with python django. Thoughts on how I can get to it? I've tried treating it like a list but didn't have any luck.

```
[(u'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACae738c5e6aaf12ffa887440a3143e55b/Messages/MM673cd77ab21b37ae435c1d1d5e767366/Media/ME33be4a0ae88358aaef2aa0ea25f31339', u'image/jpeg')]
```

Comment: is the string `"[(u'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACae738c5e6aaf12ffa887440a3143e55b/Messages/MM673cd77ab21b37ae435c1d1d5e767366/Media/ME33be4a0ae88358aaef2aa0ea25f31339', u'image/jpeg')]"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your value is a list with one tuple with two items. So get the first of each using the `0th` index:

```
lt = [(u'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACae738c5e6aaf12ffa887440a3143e55b/Messages/MM673cd77ab21b37ae435c1d1d5e767366/Media/ME33be4a0ae88358aaef2aa0ea25f31339', u'image/jpeg')]


url = lt[0][0]
print(url)    
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACae738c5e6aaf12ffa887440a3143e55b/Messages/MM673cd77ab21b37ae435c1d1d5e767366/Media/ME33be4a0ae88358aaef2aa0ea25f31339
```

If your value is actually a string CONTAINING the list, you can get a list by using `ast`:

```
import ast
lt = ast.literal_eval(lt)
```

... then use the above code to access the inner contents of the list.

Comment: It worked perfect thanks! (if was a string containing the list)

Comment: awesome, glad to help!